# Android volley library POST REQUEST ERROR

Tags: android

Someone to help me about this error
[image of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u4Dy.png)

thanks!

Comment: The error tells you that you forget to add the Error listener.

Comment: Post your codes and errors as TEXT, not as IMAGE/s

Answer (score 0):

You must diklaration/adding a ErrorListener

```
public class MyRequest {

    private Context context;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public MyRequest(Context context, RequestQueue queue) {
        this.context = context;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void register(String pseudo, String password, String password2) {
        String url = "http://192.168.56.1/don/connexion.php";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question about Post Request but Your Code is Get Request.......
try this for POST,

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                //Success 
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    //Failure
                            }
                        }) {

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put(KEY_USERNAME, user);
                        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pass);
                        return params;
                    }
                };
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            queue.add(stringRequest);
```

and you have to pass some params if you need to use Post method